# ASP.NET Session State Server: Stored Object is NULL

Tags: asp.net, session, session-state

I have set up an ASP.NET Session State Server on a SQL Database:

```
<sessionState timeout="60" allowCustomSqlDatabase="true" mode="SQLServer" sqlConnectionString="..." />
```

I have a default redirect on errors:

```
<customErrors mode="On" defaultRedirect="~/Error.aspx" />
```

Global.asax.cs:

```
private void Application_Error( object sender, EventArgs e )
{
    SomeSessionObj sessionObj = new SomeSessionObj();
    sessionObj.SomeProperty1 = true;
    sessionObj.SomeProperty2 = new Blabla();
    HttpContext.Current.Session["FooBar"] = sessionObj;
}
```

Error.aspx.cs:

```
protected void Page_Load( object sender, EventArgs e )
{
    SomeSessionObj sessionObj = HttpContext.Current.Session["FooBar"] as SomeSessionObj;
    // sessionObj is NOT NULL
    // sessionObj.SomeProperty1 is false
    // sessionObj.SomeProperty2 is NULL
}
```

Both SomeSessionObj and SomeProperty classes are marked as Serializable.

Without State Server (inProc) it works as expected.

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Ok, got it working.

When using Session State Server you have to call Server.ClearError() within Application_Error, otherwise the Request will be terminated and Session state will not be written.

```
void Application_Error(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    Exception ex = Server.GetLastError();
    HttpContext.Current.Session["Error"] = ex.Message;
    Response.Redirect("error.aspx",false);
    Server.ClearError();  
}
```